# Is it possible to restrict QListWidget so users can only select 3 items max?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qlistwidget

I know that you can change the selection mode to select more than one item from a list.  However, changing to multiselection means users can choose to select all items in a list if they wanted to.  I was wondering if it was possible to allow users to select multiple items but set a max number of items (ie users can select 1-3 items from a list of 20 items).

I've looked through the documentation and various questions, but can't see any methods that would do this.

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QAbstractItemView, QApplication, QListWidget, QListWidgetItem, QVBoxLayout, QWidget

class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(50,50,320,200)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        combo = QListWidget(self)
        combo.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.MultiSelection)
        counter = 1
        while (counter < 21):
            combo.addItem(str(counter))
            counter = counter + 1
        layout.addWidget(combo)
        self.setWindowTitle("QListWidget")
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

My example code displays a list of 20 items.  It has multiselection set so users can select multiple but no current restrictions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to subclass `QListWidget` and override `selectionCommand`, e.g.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QItemSelectionModel

class MyListWidget(QListWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, max_selected = 3):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.max_selected = max_selected

    def selectionCommand(self, index, event):
        if len(self.selectedItems()) >= self.max_selected:
            return QItemSelectionModel.Deselect
        else:
            return super().selectionCommand(index, event)
```

Comment: Oh, that makes sense!  Do you know if it's possible to override selectionCommand on a preexisting list as well?

Answer (score 1):

Okay an excerpt from the documentation found here:
https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtWidgets/QAbstractItemView.html

States the following:

> Note that the range is not updated until the widget is shown.
>
> Several other functions are concerned with selection control; for
>   example setSelectionMode() , and setSelectionBehavior() . This class
>   provides a default selection model to work with ( selectionModel() ),
>   but this can be replaced by using setSelectionModel() with an instance
>   of QItemSelectionModel

So yes it is possible to do this (as it is with all coding endeavors -- anything is possible) and the above states the how you just need to figure out how you are going to implement it -- probably going to need to use Behavior or maybe make your own Model

Answer (score 0):

This may work for similiar cases.

`list` is a `QListWidget` defined in `example.ui`. change `3` in `len(selected_items) > 3` to any value you desire.

```
ui_filename = "example.ui"
baseUIClass, baseUIWidget = uic.loadUiType(ui_filename)

class Example(baseUIWidget, baseUIClass):
    

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Example, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.list.itemSelectionChanged.connect(self.Enforce_Selection_Size)

    def Enforce_Selection_Size(self):
            selected_items = self.list.selectedItems()
            if len(selected_items) > 3:
                selected_items[3].setSelected(False)
```